# Magento 1.7.0.2 moved to new server, blank page after product add to cart

Tags: magento-1.7

I am having a problem and I am really stuck. I've tried most of the answers that I found, but I nothing works.

My problem:

I transferred a Magento 1.7.0.2 in a new server.

I've added to my host file the lines to show my eshop domain with the new server ip (example SERVER.IP www.mydomain.com)

I am accessing the eshop fixed some errors and cache issues. The only problem left is that when I add a product to cart, it added successfully, but then every page is blank page.

My php memory limit is 256mb.

I don't have any php.ini in the cpanel, I've added only the default magento .htaccess . If I disable the .htaccess I receive 500 error.

I've checked with these tools:
http://www.techjam.gr/techjamwp/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/magento-check.zip
http://www.techjam.gr/techjamwp/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/magento-cleanup.zip
And everything seems correct.

I've added in the index.php

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
```

and I receive no errors at all only blank page.

Also if I turn on the developer mode I receive the following: `Notice: Undefined index: themeData  in /home/../public_html/app/design/frontend/default/../template/page/html/head.phtml on line 118`

```
<?php

$config = Mage::getStoreConfig('mtcolinusadmin/mtcolinusadmin_appearance'); 
$otherconfig = Mage::getStoreConfig('mtcolinusadmin/otherconfig'); 
$sociallink = Mage::getStoreConfig('mtcolinusadmin/otherconfig/enabled_social_link');
?>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php echo $this->getContentType() ?>" />
<title><?php echo $this->getTitle() ?></title>
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getDescription()) ?>" />
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getKeywords()) ?>" />
<meta name="author" content="Andreadis Homestores" />
<meta name="robots" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getRobots()) ?>" />
<?php if($config['theme_responsive']){?>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<?php }?>
<link rel="icon" href="<?php echo $this->getFaviconFile(); ?>" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo $this->getFaviconFile(); ?>" type="image/x-icon" />
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var BLANK_URL = '<?php echo $this->helper('core/js')->getJsUrl('blank.html') ?>';
    var BLANK_IMG = '<?php echo $this->helper('core/js')->getJsUrl('spacer.gif') ?>';
//]]>
</script>
<![endif]-->
<?php echo $this->getCssJsHtml() ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>
<?php echo $this->helper('core/js')->getTranslatorScript() ?>
<?php echo $this->getIncludes() ?> 
<?php if($config['color_panel']){?>  
<script src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB).'js/magenthemes/mt_colinus/js/mColorPicker.js';?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<?php }?>
<script>
<?php if($otherconfig['enabled_compare']>0){?>
$mtkb('.mt-actions .link-compare').live('click', function () {
    addCompare($mtkb(this), $mtkb(this).attr('href'), $mtkb(this).attr('data-id'));
    return false;
});  
$mtkb('#block-compare a.btn-remove').live('click', function () {
    removeCompare($mtkb(this).attr('href'));
    return false;
});
$mtkb('.top-compare a.btn-remove').live('click', function () { 
    removeCompare($mtkb(this).attr('href'));
    return false;
});
$mtkb('#block-compare a.btn-remove-all').live('click', function () {
    clearCompare($mtkb(this).attr('href'));
    return false;
});
$mtkb('.top-compare a.btn-remove-all').live('click', function () { 
    clearCompare($mtkb(this).attr('href'));
    return false;
});
<?php }?>
<?php if($otherconfig['enabled_wisthlist']>0){?>
$mtkb('.mt-actions .link-wishlist').live('click', function () {
    addWishlist($mtkb(this), $mtkb(this).attr('href'),$mtkb(this).attr('data-id'));
    return false;
}); 
$mtkb('#block-wisthlist a.btn-remove').live('click', function () {
    removeWishlist($mtkb(this).attr('href'));
    return false;
});
<?php }?>
<?php if($otherconfig['enabled_ajax']){?>
$mtkb(function($) {
    $('.btn-cart').live('click', function () {
        var cart = $('.top-cart'); 
        var pass = true;   
        if($(this).parents("#block-related").length>0 || $(this).parents("#block-upsell").length>0){
            var currentImg = $(this).parents('.content').find('a.product-image img');
        }else{
            if($(this).parents('.product-view').length>0){
                var currentImg = $(this).parents('.product-view').find('a.cloud-zoom img');
            }else{
                var currentImg = $(this).parents('.content').find('a.product-image img');
            } 
        }
        if($(this).parents('.products-list-inner').length>0){
            var eload = $(this).parents('.products-list-inner').find(".ajax-loading-list").show();
        }else{
            var eload = $(this).parents('.top-actions-inner').find(".ajax-loading").show();
        }
        <?php if(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'product' && Mage::app()->getRequest()->getActionName() == 'view') {?>
        var qty = parseInt($('#qty').val()); 
        if(!qty>0){
            pass = false;
        } 
        <?php }?> 
        if($('.quickview').length>0){
            pass = false;
        }
        if (currentImg && pass) {
            var imgclone = currentImg.clone()
                .offset({ top:currentImg.offset().top, left:currentImg.offset().left })
                .addClass('imgfly')
                .css({'opacity':'0.7', 'position':'absolute', 'height':'180px', 'width':'180px', 'z-index':'1000'})
                .appendTo($('body'))
                .animate({
                    'top':cart.offset().top + 10,
                    'left':cart.offset().left + 10,
                    'width':55,
                    'height':55
                }, 1000, 'easeInOutExpo'); 
            imgclone.animate({'width':0, 'height':0});
        }
        return false;
    });
});
<?php }?>



</script>
<?php

$themeData = Mage::helper('core')->jsonDecode($_COOKIE['themeData']);

$link_color = isset($themeData['linkColor']) ? $themeData['linkColor'] : $config['link_color'];
$link_hover_color = isset($themeData['linkHoverColor']) ? $themeData['linkHoverColor'] : $config['link_hover_color'];
$link_active_color = isset($themeData['linkActiveColor']) ? $themeData['linkActiveColor'] : $config['link_active_color'];

$text_color = isset($themeData['textColor']) ? $themeData['textColor'] : $config['text_color'];
$bg_color = isset($themeData['bodyColor']) ? $themeData['bodyColor'] : $config['bg_color'];
$body_pattern = isset($themeData['bodyPattern']) ? $themeData['bodyPattern'] : $config['pattern_body_select']; 
$header_pattern = isset($themeData['headerPattern']) ? $themeData['headerPattern'] : $config['pattern_header_select'];
$top_pattern = isset($themeData['topPattern']) ? $themeData['topPattern'] : $config['pattern_top_select'];
$pattern_copyright = isset($themeData['patternCopyright']) ? $themeData['patternCopyright'] : $config['pattern_copyright_select'];
$footer_pattern = isset($themeData['footerPattern']) ? $themeData['footerPattern'] : $config['pattern_footer_select'];

$header_bg_color = isset($themeData['HeaderbgColor']) ? $themeData['HeaderbgColor'] : $config['header_bg_color']; 
$header_link_color = isset($themeData['HeaderlinkColor']) ? $themeData['HeaderlinkColor'] : $config['header_link_color'];
$header_link_hover_color = isset($themeData['HeaderlinkHoverColor']) ? $themeData['HeaderlinkHoverColor'] : $config['header_link_hover_color'];
$header_link_active_color = isset($themeData['HeaderlinkActiveColor']) ? $themeData['HeaderlinkActiveColor'] : $config['header_link_active_color'];
$header_text_color = isset($themeData['HeadertextColor']) ? $themeData['HeadertextColor'] : $config['header_text_color'];

$top_bg_color = isset($themeData['TopbgColor']) ? $themeData['TopbgColor'] : $config['top_bg_color']; 
$top_bg_hover_color = isset($themeData['TopbgHoverColor']) ? $themeData['TopbgHoverColor'] : $config['top_bg_hover_color']; 

$top_link_color = isset($themeData['ToplinkColor']) ? $themeData['ToplinkColor'] : $config['top_link_color'];
$top_link_hover_color = isset($themeData['ToplinkHoverColor']) ? $themeData['ToplinkHoverColor'] : $config['top_link_hover_color'];
$top_link_active_color = isset($themeData['ToplinkActiveColor']) ? $themeData['ToplinkActiveColor'] : $config['top_link_active_color'];
$top_text_color = isset($themeData['ToptextColor']) ? $themeData['ToptextColor'] : $config['top_text_color'];

$icons_bg_color = isset($themeData['IconsbgColor']) ? $themeData['IconsbgColor'] : $config['icons_bg_color'];
$icons_bg_hover_color = isset($themeData['IconsbgHoverColor']) ? $themeData['IconsbgHoverColor'] : $config['icons_bg_hover_color'];

$buttons_bg_color = isset($themeData['ButtonsbgColor']) ? $themeData['ButtonsbgColor'] : $config['buttons_bg_color'];
$buttons_bg_hover_color = isset($themeData['ButtonsbgHoverColor']) ? $themeData['ButtonsbgHoverColor'] : $config['buttons_bg_hover_color'];
$buttons_text_color = isset($themeData['ButtonstextColor']) ? $themeData['ButtonstextColor'] : $config['buttons_text_color'];
$buttons_text_hover_color = isset($themeData['ButtonstextHoverColor']) ? $themeData['ButtonstextHoverColor'] : $config['buttons_text_hover_color'];
$addtocart_bg_color = isset($themeData['AddtocartbgColor']) ? $themeData['AddtocartbgColor'] : $config['addtocart_bg_color'];
$addtocart_bg_hover_color = isset($themeData['AddtocartbgHoverColor']) ? $themeData['AddtocartbgHoverColor'] : $config['addtocart_bg_hover_color'];

$mainmenu_bg_color = isset($themeData['MainmenubgColor']) ? $themeData['MainmenubgColor'] : $config['mainmenu_bg_color'];
$mainmenu_dropdown_bg_color = isset($themeData['MainmenubgDropDownColor']) ? $themeData['MainmenubgDropDownColor'] : $config['mainmenu_dropdown_bg_color'];
$mainmenu_bg_hover_color = isset($themeData['MainmenubgHoverColor']) ? $themeData['MainmenubgHoverColor'] : $config['mainmenu_bg_hover_color']; 
$mainmenu_bg_active_color = isset($themeData['MainmenubgActiveColor']) ? $themeData['MainmenubgActiveColor'] : $config['mainmenu_bg_active_color']; 
$mainmenu_link_color = isset($themeData['MainmenulinkColor']) ? $themeData['MainmenulinkColor'] : $config['mainmenu_link_color'];
$mainmenu_link_hover_color = isset($themeData['MainmenulinkHoverColor']) ? $themeData['MainmenulinkHoverColor'] : $config['mainmenu_link_hover_color'];
$mainmenu_link_active_color = isset($themeData['MainmenulinkActiveColor']) ? $themeData['MainmenulinkActiveColor'] : $config['mainmenu_link_active_color'];
$mainmenu_link_sub_hover_color = isset($themeData['MainmenulinkSubHoverColor']) ? $themeData['MainmenulinkSubHoverColor'] : $config['mainmenu_link_sub_hover_color'];
$mainmenu_text_color = isset($themeData['MainmenutextColor']) ? $themeData['MainmenutextColor'] : $config['mainmenu_text_color'];

$copyright_bg_color = isset($themeData['CopyrightbgColor']) ? $themeData['CopyrightbgColor'] : $config['copyright_bg_color'];
$copyright_text_color = isset($themeData['CopyrighttextColor']) ? $themeData['CopyrighttextColor'] : $config['copyright_text_color'];
$copyright_link_color = isset($themeData['CopyrightlinkColor']) ? $themeData['CopyrightlinkColor'] : $config['copyright_link_color'];
$copyright_link_hover_color = isset($themeData['CopyrightlinkHoverColor']) ? $themeData['CopyrightlinkHoverColor'] : $config['copyright_link_hover_color'];
$copyright_link_active_color = isset($themeData['CopyrightlinkActiveColor']) ? $themeData['CopyrightlinkActiveColor'] : $config['copyright_link_active_color'];

$footer_static_bg_color = isset($themeData['footer_static_bg_color']) ? $themeData['footer_static_bg_color'] : $config['footer_static_bg_color']; 
$footer_static_text_color = isset($themeData['footer_static_text_color']) ? $themeData['footer_static_text_color'] :$config['footer_static_text_color']; 
$footer_static_link_color = isset($themeData['footer_static_link_color']) ? $themeData['footer_static_link_color'] :$config['footer_static_link_color'];
$footer_static_link_hover_color = isset($themeData['footer_static_link_hover_color']) ? $themeData['footer_static_link_hover_color'] :$config['footer_static_link_hover_color'];
$footer_static_link_active_color = isset($themeData['footer_static_link_active_color']) ? $themeData['footer_static_link_active_color'] :$config['footer_static_link_active_color'];

$bfont = isset($themeData['b_font']) ? $themeData['b_font'] : $config['b_font'];
$headerfont = isset($themeData['header_font']) ? $themeData['header_font'] : $config['header_font'];
$mfont = isset($themeData['m_font']) ? $themeData['m_font'] : $config['m_font']; 
$maintopfont = isset($themeData['maintop_font']) ? $themeData['maintop_font'] : $config['maintop_font']; 
$footerfont = isset($themeData['footer_font']) ? $themeData['footer_font'] : $config['footer_font'];
$copyrightfont = isset($themeData['copyright_font']) ? $themeData['copyright_font'] : $config['copyright_font'];

$themestyles = isset($themeData['theme_styles']) ? $themeData['theme_styles'] : $config['theme_styles'];  
?>
```

Could this error be from trying to access the magento eshop from the ip (since I am, through the host file)?

Comment: If you could paste the content of  head.phtml in the question it will be helpful to answer

Comment: ok I've edit the question and add it

Comment: Check the code where you have set the themeData to cookie

Comment: where do I check this?

Comment: Is it possible the problem occur from the session cookie? If I didn't make it clear before the files are in the new server, but I access them by changing my pc host file and point the domain name to new server ip. When I browse to the eshop everything working great. But when I add a product to the cart, then I get a blank page in every page.

Comment: It may be a issue

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, contact the host and ask them what is the memory limit set for the account. In my case it was set to low, so no matter what I set for the phpmemory it still had a lower memory limit.

Comment: I have a dedicated and access to whm. How can I check this?

Comment: I have no idea, I always contacted the hosting company and they resolved it for me.

Comment: I've just checked the memory limit of the php in the server configuration and it is set to 256Mb. Shall I increase it?

Comment: Try setting to 512Mb.

Comment: I've set it to 512mb, but still blank page.

Comment: Okay, then it's something else. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

You have posted stripped head.phtml
Please post the exact line 118 which contains the following:
`jsonDecode($_COOKIE['themeData']);`

If there is something like this:
`$themeData = jsonDecode($_COOKIE['themeData']);`
so replace it with the following:
`$themeData = isset($_COOKIE['themeData']) ? jsonDecode($_COOKIE['themeData']) : array();`